# Assigning a number for each result without adding a column in the DB - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query to return the $steps :

```
$steps = Step::where('g_id', $id)->get();

return view('showg', ['step' => $steps]);
```

The results are a group of objects looped in a foreach. I'm trying to add a rank to each step, which will show the number of the step. It should simply start from one until the end of the steps.

Is there an easy way instead of creating a step_number column for this purpose ?

```
 @foreach ($step as $steps)   
     <div>{{ $steps->step_number }}</div>                                             
     <div>{{ $steps->step }}</div>   

 @endforeach
```

Comment: By ranking you mean steps with the same values must take the same rank, or you just need a serial number?

Comment: Yes, I need a serial number for each step to be shown in the view

Comment: Use a simple counter like $counter = 0; before the loop and then inside the loop <div>{{++$counter}}</div>

Comment: Use the `$loop->iteration` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $counter = 0 ?>
@foreach ($step as $steps)   
     <div>{{ ++$counter }}</div>
     <div>{{ $steps->step_number }}</div>                                             
     <div>{{ $steps->step }}</div>   
@endforeach
```

I hope it helps